# Pseudo-scalar product on Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to study the Semi-Riemannian Manifold and the relativity (I use the book Semi-Riemannian Manifold- O'Neill). But I don't understand the following thing:
In a Semi-Riemannnian Manifold, I can define a pseudo-scalar product on each tangent space $T_pM$ with the metric tensor $g$. But whyI have to define it on the tangent space? And if I define it on the tangent spaces, I have automatically define a pseudo-scalar product on all the manifold? If I think at a space-time, for example $\mathbb{M}^4$, the Minkosky space time,  i need only the scalar product on the tangent space to know if a curve is spacelike or timelike?
Sorry but I'm really confused. Thanks

Comment: sorry I deleted my answer. It is probably not right.

Comment: Are you familiar with the most basic terms of Riemannian geometry, namely manifolds, tangent spaces and Riemannian metric?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval Yes. I'm.

Comment: By definition, a pseudo Riemannian metric is nondegenerate bilinear form on every tangent space. This is just what it is. There isn't any meaning in "scalar product on a manifold", as we always put tangent vectors into the bilinear form, rather than points on the manifold.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval thanks for your answer. Maybe I understand something more. My problem was: if I modelize the space-time with a manifold, for instance $\mathbb{R}^4$, i would like to know, picked two point, for instance, if there is a timelike curve from this two point. And for check this I have to know if the tangent vector, in every point, are timelike. And for do this I need a pseudo-scalar product...Right??

Comment: What you're saying does make a lot of sense, so I would say it is true. However, truth needs to be told, I know nothing about space-time. I am familiar only with the geometric aspects. Please try to ask someone else your new and much more clear question.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval thank you for your time!